# Can we declare variables inside the expression of an Angular binding?

Tags: angular

I am just learning and following Adam Freeman's Angualr 6 book. In chapter 14 for Event he has this example:

```
<div class="m-2">
    <div class="text-white p-2 bg-info">
        Selected Product: {{selectedProduct || '(None)'}}
    </div>

    <table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
        <tr><th></th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th></tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of getProducts(); let i=index">
            <td (mouseover)="selectedProduct=item.name">{{ i+1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{item.category}}</td>
            <td>{{item.price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I think it is wrong! Because look at that `selectedProduct` variable that gets its value on that `MouseOver` event. I don't see it defined in the component side. So either it is wrong or it is an Angular thing that I don't know yet.

Also here is the component for it:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
})
export class ProductComponent {
    model: Model = new Model();

    getProduct(key: number): Product{
        return this.model.getProduct(key);
    }

    getProducts(): Product[]{
        return this.model.getProducts();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh nevermind! I should've just kept reading the book! Next section title is: "Understanding DYNAMICALLY DEFINED properties" ... so yes it is an Angualr thing.

Comment: It is indeed wrong. That code will work fine in development mode, but as soon as you create a production build with the AOT compiler, the template won't compile anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can.
Because it is JavaScript. So that would be dynamic variables of JS at that point. Not a good practice but yes it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Please create variable in component then after you can use it in HTMl, and you can not create variable in HTML page in Angular